Conditions for a Markov Chain being reversible
I have a question on one of the concepts from the book Markov Chains by James Norris. This relates to thm. 1.9.3 (pg 48):
Let $P$ be an irreducible stochastic matrix and let $\lambda$ be a distribution. Suppose that $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is Markov$(\lambda, P)$. Then the following are equivalent: $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is reversible; $P$ and $\lambda$ are in detailed balance.
The book then proceeds to a exercise question that asks to see if a matrix P is reversible or not? By the theorem above, it seems that reversibility depends on the distribution $\lambda$ and the matrix P. But if only a matrix P is given, how would I see if a Markov Chain is reversible or not? Do I choose any distribution? And why?
Thanks in advance!

The stationary distribution for the MC will satisfy the detailed balance equation, if MC is reversible. However, you need to find it first, using the usual equation for the global balance, $\lambda=\lambda P$.

It is sometimes said that the transition matrix $P$ of a Markov chain is reversible if there exists a measure $\lambda$ on the state space of the chain so that detailed balance holds: $\lambda_i P_{i,j} = \lambda_jP_{j,i}$ for all states $i$ and $j$. And then $\lambda$ might be called a reversing measure. (By measure I intend it to be understood that $\lambda_i\ge 0$ for all $i$.) Because $P$ is stochastic (row sums equal to $1$), a reversing measure $\lambda$ is necessarily an invariant measure. (The converse need not hold.)
The chain being irreducible, if it's recurrent then there is at most one invariant measure (up to a constant multiple). A fortiori there is at most one reversing measure (up to multiples).
